# Remote Validation doesnt receive the field value when is a FILE type

Tags: c#, asp.net, unobtrusive-validation

I have a controller where user select a File with data to be load in the system, but I need to validate the file hasnt already been load before so I try to create a `Remote` Validation

I create a class:

```
public class FileUpload
{
    [Display(Name = "Archivo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe seleccionar un archivo.") ]
    [Remote("BackupFileExist", "ImportJobs", ErrorMessage = "El archivo ya fue cargado.")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Test")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe seleccionar un archivo.")]
    [Remote("BackupTestExist", "ImportJobs", ErrorMessage = "El archivo ya fue cargado.")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

and a strong type view with `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Test, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Test, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Test, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Cargar Archivo" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section scripts {
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

Then my controller:

```
public class ImportJobsController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult BackupFileExist(HttpPostedFileBase File)
    {
        return Json(!db.ImportJobs.Any(f => f.FileName == File.FileName), 
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult BackupTestExist(string Test)
    {
        return Json(!db.ImportJobs.Any(f => f.FileName == Test), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

My issue is the `BackupFileExist` function is call but the `File` variable is null

**Edit:** After posting the question I decide add a `Test` field with type string. That field work as expected. So looks like is an issue with the `File` type

Comment: BackupFileExist` should accept `FileUpload` as parameter.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Nope, FileUpload is the class, have to receive the field you want to validate. I will add more info. Because I just add a string field for testing and is working as expected. Looks like the problem is because is a file.